# Thinnest operating system supporting virtualization apps like VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, operating-system, virtualbox

What is the thinnest (*in size and resource needs*) x64 operating system that can be used to execute virtualbox for near bare metal performance. Linux distribution are not crash-proof and often drivers are not detected - thus thinlinux is ruled out.

Comment: I've edited this question to get rid of question limit ban and in turn got -3. We know deleting will not help and neither editing. How can I remove such questions to improve rating -- please advice ?

Comment: @SecurityHound - the question is far too old, at over a year, to be migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist rancher (http://rancher.com/rancher-os/) which can solve this problem as follows

- Its a 30-40mb operating system as bootable ISO so no questions of crash with power outages, can always reboot from ISO.
- One can load docker images which shall be of Ubuntu / Windows thereby eliminating footprint needs in terms of thin OS and no requirement of VMWare / Virtual Box.

Still need to find out how to convert a virtual image to docker image like vmdk's etc.